# Como descobrir o encoding original de um nome de arquivo (ou uma string qualquer)?

Tags: codificação-de-caracteres

Tenho uma série de arquivos que parecem ter sido gerados em diferentes sistemas operacionais, pois a codificação de caracteres de seus nomes parece variar entre eles.

Há nomes cujos acentos aparecem normalmente para mim, tanto em OSX quanto em Linux (com terminal configurado em UTF-8 em ambos os casos), enquanto outros ficaram estranhos. Por exemplo, tem um trecho em que vejo `APRESENTAÇO_MAR_2015` onde claramente a palavra deveria ser `APRESENTAÇÃO`.

Olhando com mais cuidado o trecho problemático `ÇO`, encontrei 5 valores (em hexadecimal):

```
0xC2
0x80
0x43
0x327
0x4F
```

Tentei converter a string com `iconv`, variando as codificações de entrada e saída, mas não consegui o resultado desejado (`ÇÃO`). Como descobrir a codificação original desses nomes e corrigi-los? Tenho muitos arquivos com problema, e gostaria de resolver isso programaticamente.

Comment: Bom, creio que sua pergunta seja referente a php, para descobrir o enconding você pode utilizar esta função `mb_detect_encoding()`

Comment: Na verdade posso resolver em qualquer linguagem de programação, até mesmo no shell. Só não sei como. Vou testar essa função do PHP e já digo o resultado.

Comment: @GuilhermeLopes O `mb_detect_encoding` retorna UTF-8, o que não deixa de ser verdade no meu sistema. Porém acredito que esse não seja o encoding original do nome do arquivo.

Comment: É, realmente, não sei se retorna o encoding original do nome do arquivo, fiz alguns testes, dê uma olhada: https://ideone.com/VJrQks

Comment: Parece não ser possível, dê uma olhada aqui: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/187169/how-to-detect-the-encoding-of-a-file

Comment: Mas pelo que entendi essa pergunta é sobre o conteúdo dos arquivos, e meu problema é com o nome deles. Entendo que no nome não haja mesmo nenhuma informação sobre encoding (como pode haver no header de um arquivo), mas estou buscando maneiras de pelo menos poder inferir a codificação para poder corrigir os nomes dos arquivos com problema.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34656/discussion-between-guilherme-lopes-and-bfavaretto).

Comment: Eu resolvi um problema semelhante usando a função  ucsdet_detect() da lib icu. Com ela você pode detectar o charset de qualquer string. No meu caso foi o tratamento de um arquivo que continha linhas em charsets diferentes.

Comment: @bfavaretto, estou entendendo que você quer tentar descobrir o enconding de uma string qualquer. Será que isso ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910793/detect-encoding-and-make-everything-utf-8

Comment: É complicado pois depende do ambiente. Por exemplo  se vai resolver isso em php tem umas técnicas específicas, se vai resolver com visual studio é outro jeito, se vai fazer em java ou no prompt do windows, é outro jeito. Seria melhor definir em qual ambiente e com qual ferramentas pretende usar.

Comment: Estou achando que vai ser impossível ou muito complicado, pois parece haver encoding em cima de encoding nos arquivos. Vou fechar a pergunta. @DanielOmine

Comment: @cantoni Tentei o que diz lá, mas fiquei ainda mais confuso. Agora acho que está ficando mais claro, mas a pergunta talvez não seja respondível. Veja meu comentário para o Daniel Omine, logo acima. Obrigado!

Comment: @bfavaretto, realmente é um problema chato de lidar. É aquele tipo de problema onde o tempo que você vai gastar escrevendo uma solução automática inviabiliza a mesma.

Comment: @cantoni É exatamente o que estou sentindo. Ou vou resolver na unha, ou vou pedir para o próprio cliente (que me passou os arquivos) resolver.

Answer (score -1):

Navegue até a pasta e digite:

```
file -I meuarquivo.extensao
```

Caso seja um resultado vindo de um banco de dados, pode utilizar a linguagem PHP para descobrir o charset utilizando a função mb_check_encoding.

```php
if(mb_check_encoding($row['campo'], 'UTF-8')){
    echo"verdadeiro";
}else{
    echo"falso";
}
```

Comment: O `file -I` deu `application/zip; charset=binary` (o arquivo é um pptx).